# View does not refresh on IPC message received

Tags: angular, electron, ipc

My component correctly receives a message (as I could see with the debugger), but its view is not refreshed. Is there any manual operation to be done in the IPC listener?

This is my component HTML code:

`<div>
  {{text}}
</div>`

And this is the TypeScript:

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron'

 @Component({
   selector: 'app-receiver',
   templateUrl: './receiver.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./receiver.component.scss']
 })
 export class ReceiverComponent implements OnInit {
   text: string;

 constructor() { }

 ngOnInit() {
  ipcRenderer.on('msg', function (event, arg){
    this.text=arg;
     })
   }
 }
```

I expect the new string the page receives from Electron process to be shown on the page, but it doesn't happen

Comment: the `ipcRenderer` most likely runs outside of the angular zone, or you may not be scoping correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event handling of IPC runs outside of the angular zone. The event is not so called 'monkey patched'. You should apply the change inside a `ngZone.run` call. Besides that, you are using the `function` keyword, which causes the `this` context to change to that function, and cannot access the class `this` anymore. Use the arrow notation:

```
constructor(readonly nz: NgZone) { }

ngOnInit() {
  ipcRenderer.on('msg', (event, arg) => {
    this.nz.run(() => this.text = arg);
  });
}
```

Don't forget to 'unlisten' for msg in the `ngOnDestroy` though, otherwise you trigger a detectChanges on a destroyed directive, and angular doesn't like that :)

Comment: using arrow functions changes scoping, not the zones. to run in the angular zone you need to import `ngZone` and then `run()` the code and it will be in the zone

Comment: @mast3rd3mon absolutely right, don't know why I made him use the `changeDetector`. It will work though (I think), but it's not the right way. I've updated my answer to make it work for sure. Thanks for heads-up